Power Pivot Model: How to change existing existing connection source from excel workbook to table loaded as query connection?
enter image description hereWe have a power pivot model already build with DAX formulas and measures where the data sources are excel workbooks on someone's local drive on laptop.
Since this power pivot model needs to be used by several members in teams, we need to have all the connections to files on the web (sharepoint web link). As direct connection does not work to sharepoint weblinks for the power pivot model but works for power query connections. I will like to have all the files loaded into power query (load as connection) and then load into powerpivot..
So how can I replace all the connection links in power pivot model from excel workbook to power query connections without having to redo the entire powerpivot model?
i.e connection type from an excel workbook to weblink...
please help..
replace all the connection links in power pivot model from excel workbook to power query connections without having to redo the entire powerpivot model

I don't think that's possible. If the workbook is referenced as a direct connection in the Data Model, you can't change that to a Power Query.
